# How to make an image the bottom layer in Sharepoint 2013 Content Editor Web Part

Tags: html, css, sharepoint

I have an image I want to make the background(bottom layer) so I can put text and other images over it in the content editor web part of Sharepoint 2013. The formatting ribbon does not have this editing function and the code doesn't look like CSS or HTML I've been able to adapt through a google search.

Anyone have any ideas?

Here's the code for the image:

```
<p dir="ltr"> 
   <span style="color: #646569;">
      <img src="/Sites/Resource/PublishingImages/Blue%20ADP%20background.png" -1;alt="Blue ADP background.png" alt="" style="margin: 5px;"/></span>&#160;</p> 
<ol dir="ltr" style="margin-right: 0px;"> 
   <ol>
   </ol>
</ol>
```

Comment: content editor web part just show whatever HTML/JS u put on it.
try using CSS classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<style>
.bgimage {
    background-image: url("yourbg.jpg");
    width: 100%;
}
.content {
    width: 100%;
}
</style>

<div class="bgimage">
    <div class"content">
        Put your content here
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Craig B glad to hear,  one thing i forgot to mention,  Sharepoint uses HUNDREDS of classes,  make sure yours are going to be unique,  microsoft for example puts `ms-` in front of all of thiers,  but that doesn't mean other devs are going to be as nice,   so do something like `cb-bgimage`  and `cb-content`  or if you work for company ABC (lucky you) put `abc-cb-content`   as an example,  this will make sure it's unique, as a CSS class is a page wide thing,  there is no scope.